# Using specific resources for android testing

Tags: android, tdd

I'm trying to test an android project. I'm using intellij IDEA.

So far everything goes perfect. My problem arises when I try to use a different xml resource file for the tests (with specific data for testing) instead of using the XML resource from the tested project.

I have the following directory structure:

Project
|
|---- assets
|---- res
|-------|---- values
|-------|---- xml
|---- src
|---- tests
---------|----res
---------|------|-----xml
---------|-----src

I've assumed that the XML stored in the Project/tests/res/xml would automatically replace the one stored in Project/res/xml when running under the context of the test. It is not happening so, the tests keep on taking the Project/res/xml file instead of the test xml.

Do I have to make anything additional? Is there a way to somewhat mock this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can place your XML files in the `resource` or `assets` folder of your **test** project and access them by:

```
InputStream myxml = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("my_document.xml");
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Yes, I can! But the problem is that the object that I'm calling is still using the "R" object from the tested project, so it references another XML that has the same name but is different. My point is that this should be automatic (having custom data for TDD is very common). Is there any way to make the class automatically switch from XML directory ? I was hoping that android would have some scheme similar to the one that uses with "drawable" and "drawable-es" directories, where if the file is found in "drawable-es" replaces the one in "drawable"...

Comment: Please give a more precise example of what you want to achieve and what you've done and didn't work.